# Country state city picklist

Tags: apex, visualforce

How to get the Country,State,City Pick list in Visual force.
By selecting the country , it needs to show the states in the selected country in dropdown , by selecting the state it needs to display the cities in the state.
How to achieve this in Visual force page>

Comment: Have you tried with googling about this question .

Answer (score 0):

Dependent fields provide a way to filter the field values displayed on a Visualforce page. Dependent fields consist of two parts: a controlling field that determines the filtering, and a dependent field that has its values filtered.

Check This:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_dependent_picklists.htm

Comment: Thanks, Is there any possibility automatically getting all the countries and sates&cities instead of adding dependent picklist

Comment: If you have added all picklist values to picklist field.It will be generally available.

Answer (score 0):

//Apex class

```
  public class CountryStateController {
  public String state {get;set;}
  public String city {get;set;}

public List<SelectOption> getStates() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('None','--- None ---'));        
    options.add(new SelectOption('RJ','Rajasthan'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('MH','Maharastra'));
    return options;
} 

public List<SelectOption> getCities(){
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    if(state == 'RJ')
    {       
        options.add(new SelectOption('AJM','AJMER'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('JAI','JAIPUR'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('JOD','JODHPUR'));
    }
    else if(state == 'MH') {       
        options.add(new SelectOption('Mub','Mumbai'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('PUN','Pune'));
    }
    else {
        options.add(new SelectOption('None','--- None ---'));
    }      
    return options;
}
```

}

//VF page

```
<apex:page controller="CountryStateController ">

<apex:form >

<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
        <apex:pageblockSectionItem>
            <apex:outputLabel value="State"/>
        </apex:pageblockSectionItem>        
        <apex:pageblockSectionItem>                
            <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!state}">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!states}"/>
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="city"/>
            </apex:selectList>                
        </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageblockSectionItem>
            <apex:outputLabel value="City"/>
        </apex:pageblockSectionItem>            
        <apex:pageblockSectionItem>
            <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!city}" id="city">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!cities}"/>
            </apex:selectList>
        </apex:pageblockSectionItem>            
    </apex:pageBlockSection>        
</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
```